# ST2 and Emacs: Delete Whole / Entire Word + Whitespace to the right

Tags: emacs, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Coming from a word processing background, the behavior I have become accustomed to seeing for `delete word` is the following:  delete entire word plus all of the whitespace after the word.  I am assuming that the plugin `delete_word.py` (within `/Packages/Default`) preserves whitespace for those with a programming background.

To approximate the behavior that I am accustomed to seeing, it is necessary to place the cursor at the end of the preceding word, to delete the following word (so that only one whitespace remains between both words when done).

Is there another keyboard shortcut already built-in to Sublime that would accomplish the behavior to which I am most accustomed?

Comment: what is `delete_word.py`?

Comment: `delete_word.py` is the python script plugin that is in the folder `/Packages/Default`. It is linked to the OSX/Mac keymap of `"ctrl+backspace"` or `"ctrl+delete"`, depending upon whether the user wants to delete forwards or backwards.  I'll edit the question to add the word plugin.

Comment: Using code editors more than word processors, I find it quite annoying that word processors remove more than just the word with ctrl+backspace, even if it's an extra period or apostrophe. I have no idea why it's annoying, but it just feels so.

Comment: That is sort of what I imagined -- people who have spent years of coding expect a particular behavior; whereas diehard word processors expect something totally different.  I am now using SublimeText2 for everything (including word processing with LaTeX), but I'm not sure I'll ever get use to breaking old habits of having been a secretary all of those years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution # 1 -- Sublime Text 2:

For whatever the reason, `super+d` aka `⌘+d` aka `find_under_expand` do **not** work with macros.  `find_under_expand` does not appear to be a plugin.  So, here is a sample select-entire-word plugin that does work with macros:

```
 import sublime, sublime_plugin

 class Expand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
     def run(self, edit):
         regions = []
         for s in self.view.sel():
             word = self.view.word(sublime.Region(s.begin(), s.end()))
             if word.end() == s.end():
             # to deal with an end of line issue
                 word = self.view.word(sublime.Region(s.end(), s.end() + 1))
             regions.append(word)
         for r in regions:
             self.view.sel().add(r)
```

Next, install the Shrink-Whitespaces plugin written by `dacap`:

https://github.com/dacap/sublime-shrink-whitespaces.

Then, create this macro.  Shrinking the whitespace two (2) times deals with situations where there are tabs or tabs+spaces.

```
[
 {
      "args": null,
      "command": "expand"
 },
 {
      "args": null,
      "command": "right_delete"
 },
 {
      "args": null,
      "command": "shrink_whitespaces"
 },
 {
      "args": null,
      "command": "shrink_whitespaces"
 },
 {
      "args":
      {
           "characters": " "
      },
      "command": "insert"
 }
]
```

---

Solution # 2 -- Sublime Text 2:

Install:  https://github.com/bits/ExpandSelectionToWhitespace-SublimeText

Create a macro and bind it to your favorite keyboard shortcut:

```
[
    {
        "args": null,
        "command": "expand_selection_to_whitespace"
    },
    {
        "args":
        {
            "by": "wordends",
            "extend": true,
            "forward": true
        },
        "command": "move"
    },
    {
        "args":
        {
            "by": "words",
            "extend": true,
            "forward": false
        },
        "command": "move"
    },
    {
        "args": null,
        "command": "left_delete"
    }
]
```

---

Solution # 1 -- Emacs -- define two functions, and create a macro:

```
(fset 'lawlist-kill-word [?\C-= kp-delete ?\C-+])

(global-set-key (kbd "C-=") 'lawlist-mark-word)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-+") 'delete-horizontal-space-forward)

(defun lawlist-mark-word ()
  "Mark the entire symbol around or in front of point."
  (interactive)
  (let ((symbol-regexp "\\s_\\|\\sw"))
    (when (or (looking-at symbol-regexp)
              (looking-back symbol-regexp))
      (skip-syntax-forward "_w")
      (set-mark (point))
      (while (looking-back symbol-regexp)
        (backward-char)))))

(defun delete-horizontal-space-forward () ; adapted from `delete-horizontal-space'
      "*Delete all spaces and tabs after point."
      (interactive "*")
      (delete-region (point) (progn (skip-chars-forward " \t") (point))))
```

Comment: delete-horizontal-space-forward ()
Thank you, that is what I need exactly, not sure why there is no delete-horizontal-space equivalent by default.